# función sorted()

Tags: python

¿Cómo funciona la función sorted() en python?

Tengo entendido que ordena alfabéticamente, pero cuando hago:

```
xx = ['a','f','b']
sorted(xx)
prin (xx)
```

Me imprime [a,f,b]

¿Que hago o planteo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted()` toma una lista o en general un iterable como argumento y devuelve *otro* con los mismos elementos pero ordenado. El argumento que le pasas originalmente no lo modifica (y de este modo se le pueden pasar también tuplas, que son inmutables, aunque te devolvería una lista).

Si quieres que `xx` guarde la lista ordenada, tendrás que hacer:

```
xx = sorted(xx)
```

Otra posibilidad es usar el método `list.sort()` del propio objeto-lista, así:

```
xx.sort()
```

Este sí opera sobre `xx` "in situ" y la cambia.